# Possible to export Xamarin.iOS project to Xamarin.watchOS project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, watchos-2

I have a very basic ios app made in Xamarin and was wondering if anyone knows if there is some way to translate or export the project to work for the watchOS system? Is there any way to add a watchOS build to an existing Xamarin Project?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a watch extension project to your solution. And then you will have to create your watchOS UI in the extension project. See Xamarin's guide for adding a watchOS project to an iOS app project:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/